# Damaging an enemies with OverlapSphere in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overlap

I have a problem with OverlapSphere in C#. Im trying to make an explosion that deal damage to nearby enemies but if rocket hit one target it delt damage only to this one. When rocket expolde on floor or wall nearby enemies it dont delt damage.

```
    EnemyHealth target = collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
    Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Collider [] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
    foreach(Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
    {
        Collider enemy = nearbyObject.GetComponent<Collider>();

        if (enemy != null)
        {
            target.TakeDamage(damage); //this fuction deal damage to enemies
        }
```

Its fragment of my code. I dont know how to fix it, its my first game and I didnt use Unity and C# before.

Comment: Is the radius long enough to hit the targets? Are the colliders correctly matching the transforms of the targets? Are the enemy colliders in a layer that doesn't interact with the explosion? I don't see anything wrong with the code... It's probably the unity objects that are causing you trouble

Comment: target isnt changing per enemy.... so you're gonna damage the same object for every hit object

Comment: i think it can be the reason but i dont know how to fix it now. Should I make a table of all enemies on scene or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the enemies `EnemyHealth` in your loop, instead you always use the same `target` to deal the damage. You need to get the EnemyHealth component for each object collided with your sphere:

```
    Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Collider [] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
    foreach(Collider nearbyObject in colliders)
    {
        // Assuming that the enemy gameobject with the collider also holds the EnemyHealth script (!)
        EnemyHealth enemy = nearbyObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();

        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.TakeDamage(damage); //this fuction deal damage to enemies
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** it can be expensive to call `GetComponent()` so in case you do this often, you should try to cache the `EnemyHealth` components for the enemies.

Comment: Thank you for help, it fixed my problem :)